# unable to open the default mail client

Tags: c#

I am using following code to open the default mail client

```
using (Process mailProcess = new Process())
{
     ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
     processInfo.FileName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}", 
                             sendToAddress.Address, subject, message);
     processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
     processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
     mailProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
     Process.Start(processInfo);
}
```

It starts the process but doesn't show mail client.
Actually when I am using only localhost it doesn't open the mail client although it starts the process.

When I am using localhost: it works.

Can anybosy hel me?

Comment: Which email client? It works successfully with outlook.

Comment: I want to open with default mail client whichever has setup.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62c78012-8b8a-49d6-a2df-ed80aff7a8ae/how-to-format-a-c-string-to-lauch-an-email-client-so-that-the-email-had-body-text-that-has-line?forum=csharpgeneral) you need to make sure that you URL-encode the file name. It may not contain spaces or other special characters not available in URLs.

Is suspect that your subject and body at least contain spaces or newlines. You can use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this task.